# Does OpenUI5 have an open Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

While OpenUI5 looks a very interesting technology, I'm not sure what's the best way to expose it. Possibly it could be embedded in a traditional portal, but the recommended strategy for SAPUI5 seems to be the Fiori Launchpad.

However, such component is not available as open source.

Hence my question: what would be the most appropriate publishing platform for OpenUI5-based applications?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is no: there's no tool like SAP Fiori Launchpad for Open Source world. You need to write from scratch using Tile Container to simulate the look and feel of SAP Launchpad.

Comment: `class sap.m.TileContainer` now is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try WebIDE > Run > Run As > Fiori launchpad sandbox.
As it use same ushell component, look & feel is the same as Fiori launchpad. However authentication, group/tile management, authorization and personalization is not supported. It is just for Fiori app testing purpose, but it is up-to your imagination.

https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?6609d3ba857742ef99432b6b0472ade0.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "publishing platform". Fiori apps are UI5-based and hosted on a web server of any choice (HANA, NetWeaver, Tomcat, MAMP, Mongoose, etc). You can even create UI5 apps on JSBin and JSFiddle or host inside google drive or GitHub Pages. UI5 apps are based on static files, like any other traditional web app.

Comparing to the Fiori Launchpad, UI5 has components that enable you to create your own launchpad. I'm talking about the [TileContainer](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.TileContainer.html) and [Tile](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Tile.html) classes.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I understand that we could theoretically redevelop the Launchpad, but also several components like the ushell seem to be proprietary stuff i.e. not in openui5. In an ideal world, I'd like to deploy an open launchpad to my target environment (e.g. Tomcat) and then hook up all the other apps in it. Do you think there's a way to do so without recreating the launchpad from scratch?

Comment: Nothing in OpenUI5 is proprietary... it's open as the name suggests. In an ideal world, you can develop a launchpad very easily and deploy/host anywhere/anyhow you want (Tomcat is perfectly possible and has nothing to do with the question). Have you tried to create a TileContainer and a Tile inside it? It so straightforward... you won't be reinventing the wheel. Take a look on the example: http://fabiopagoti.github.io/NYT-Launchpad-UI5/app/WebContent/

Comment: The is no such thing like an "Open Launchpad". The SAP Fiori Launchpad is totally proprietary and is part of SAP Licenses.

Comment: I have looked at recreating launchpad - in the end the best approach is simply to create an applauncher page. I have my own bespoke identity provider achieving SSO across apps. Ushell (sap.ui.unified.Shell in openui5) is not proprietary. I use it off openui5 (it is deprecated from 1.44 but that doesn't worry me).